# Adding a Row To a Child Gridview

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I am trying to have a webpage  which takes values from one gridview and copies those values into another gridview. The problem is that the gridview I am trying to copy to is nested inside a parent gridview which is already databound. However, each time the page loads, the parent gridview has a function rowDataBound which overwrites the copied data of the child gridview to the parent and child's original state.

[Diagram of what my webpage should look like and how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXEl.jpg)

How do I prevent the rowDataBound from firing after I copy the data from the one grid view to the other?

I've been working on this for a while any response would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is a better point of view. You should handle the data before bind to the GridView. One simple solution is to get the data as DataTable and access the row to get data source withing the row in question.

```
DataTable myData = GetData();
DataTable dataToInject = new DataTable();

foreach(var row in myData.Rows) {
  if ((int)row["id"] ==  123) {
    dataToInject = (DataTable) row["data"];
  }
}
```

The dataToInject can be passed on rowDataBound for the right row or you pre process all your data before bind to any GridView, which I recommend. Avoid using rowDataBound and process your data in your Business Logic or on the Service layer of your application.